# How to stack flex items properly with grid (flex: 9999 hack)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to stack up two flex items when necessary, using the `flex-grow: 9999` "hack", I can achieve this by setting the "description" to have a max-width, following the correct design, but don't want to do that, since I want to have its container to follow the flow of the grid and its children to have full width (no max-width or fixed values restrictions, i.e. dynamic flow) then break when necessary, and avoid media query. The following snippet is working as expected, *but* with `.description`'s `max-width` being set with a fixed value:

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
}

section.content-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 975px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 44px;
}

section.content-wrapper .news.with-preview figure {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

section.content-wrapper .news.with-preview figure img {
  width: 100%;
}

section.content-wrapper .news.with-preview {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section.content-wrapper .news.with-preview .description {
  -webkit-box-flex: 9999;
  -ms-flex-positive: 9999;
  flex-grow: 9999;
  max-width: 228px;
}

section.content-wrapper .news {
  border-top: 3px solid #dbdbdb;
  grid-column: span 5;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 19px;
}
```

```html
<section class="content-wrapper noticias">
  <article class="news with-preview">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
    </figure>
    <div class="description">
      <h1>Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi nunc dolor, tempus eu congue id, fringilla</h1>
      <span>Amazonas</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec ex libero. Aliquam tristique egestas convallis. Vivamus ut sodales ligula…</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="news with-preview">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
    </figure>
    <div class="description">
      <h1>Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi nunc dolor, tempus eu congue id, fringilla</h1>
      <span>Amazonas</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec ex libero. Aliquam tristique egestas convallis. Vivamus ut sodales ligula…</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Perhaps it's a misconception of how flex + grid (or flex alone) works.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rhn8d20b/

Comment: i do not understand what is the expected result . https://jsfiddle.net/rhn8d20b/1/ ??

Comment: @G-Cyr the expected result is his actuall code, but for some unknown reason he want the code to behave the same with the max-width

Comment: You should try to make this question more clear. Maybe break it down a bit more, or add illustrations of your desired behavior. Also, `flex: 9999` is not really a hack, just an extreme method for allotting all free space on the line to one item.